# JPA/Hibernate Implicit join on collection attribute

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

I would like to execute a query using [implicit join](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html#queryhql-joins-forms) on a collection attribute.

Example: 
**CONTAINER** class has a one to many relationship with **CONTENT**.

The query: SELECT * FROM CONTAINER container WHERE container.content.value = "FOO"

In Dynamic query is somethink like this:

```
Root<Container> from = criteriaQuery.from(Container.class);
from.get("container").<String>get("note");
```

The problem is that I cant, as it says:
 *Illegal attempt to dereference path source [container.value] of basic type.*

I'm using JPA 2.1 with hibernate-core-4.3.5

Comment: container is a Collection? so a Collection has no such field "note"

Comment: And there is no way to get around this?

Comment: I doubt it, since you need to refer to the "element" and that would mean a join to get the reference for it